# R data.table: How to update rows by reference with column names supplied as vector?

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to update certain rows of a data.table.
However, I cant manage to access the vector with the column names.

What is the proper way?

MWE:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4))
cols <- colnames(dt)
vec <- c(9,10)
dt[2,(cols):= list(vec)] # Not working
dt[2,(..cols):= list(vec)] # Not working
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a tiny modification is required:

```
dt[2, (cols) := as.list(vec)]
```

To understand what is happening, compare the two versions:

```
as.list(vec)
# [[1]]
# [1] 9
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 10

list(vec)
# [[1]]
# [1]  9 10
```